# Http.post request to server doesn't send the body with it in flutter. On the server side, the body of request is empty. I have added the code below

Tags: json, flutter, http, post, request

```
Future<User> authUser(String username, String password) async (
Map data = {
'username' : username,
'password' : password,
};
var authUserResp = await http.post (
new Uri.http('localhost:8000','apiquery'),
headers: {
'Content-type' : 'application/json',
'Accept' : 'application/json',
},
body: json.encode(data),
);
print(authUserResp.statusCode);
return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(authUserResp.body)['data']);
)
```

The status code on successful post operation in Postman is 201 for created. But in flutter the status code being returned is 200. And on the local api server the body of request is an empty map as {}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That definition for `data` is not a `Map`.

Try correcting the map and see if this helps:

```
    Map data = {
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument in the function is 'password' instead of 'Password correct that

Comment: Yes that was a typo in the question. In the code it is correct.

Comment: I had already corrected it. The answer doesn't solve.my problem

Comment: Can't give access to my computer

Comment: what you have used for getting data for  username and password ?

Comment: A form, which returns the 2 fields as strings

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not valid.

Here is the code. I just made a few changes.

```
      Future<Usert> authUser(String username, String password) async {
Map<String, dynamic> data = {
  'username': username,
  'password': password,
};
var authUserResp = await http.post(
  new Uri.http('localhost:8000', 'apiquery'),
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  body: json.encode(data),
);
print(authUserResp.statusCode);
return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(authUserResp.body)['data']);
```

}

Comment: After posting check the console and if any bug is coming post it here.